# The property of symmetric matrices and Euclid inner product, about rank.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, matrix-rank, symmetric-matrices

Let $A,B$ symmetric matrices of $\mathbb R$ and $(\cdot, \cdot)$ be Euclid inner product.

Suppose $(Ax,x)\geqq (Bx,x)\geqq 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb R^n$.

Then, prove rank$A\geqq$ rank$B$.

---

I don't come to the conclusion by the method below.

Note rank$A\geqq$ rank$B$ $\iff \dim \ker A\leqq \dim \ker B$.

So, it suffices to show $\dim \ker A\leqq \dim \ker B$.

Let $V:=\{x\in \mathbb R^n \mid (Bx,x)=0\}.$

Then, from the condition $(Ax,x)\geqq (Bx,x)\geqq 0$, I get $\ker A\subset V.$

And if I can prove $V$ is subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ (I didn't prove and I don't know whether $V$ is subspace of $\mathbb R^n$), I get $\dim \ker A\leqq \dim V$.

---

I don't come to conclusion and I don't know whether I'm on right track.

Any idea ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given : $ A,B $ symmetric matrices of $\Bbb{R}$  and $(⋅,⋅)$ be Euclid inner product and
$(Ax,x)\geq (Bx,x)\geqq 0$

To show :  $\operatorname{rank}(A)\ge \operatorname{rank}(B) $

---

It is enough to show that $\ker(A) \subset \ker(B) $

Let $x\in \ker(A) $ then $Ax=0$  implies $0=(Ax,x)\geq (Bx,x)\geq 0$

Hence $(Bx, x) =0$

Let $y\in\Bbb{R}^n$ , then by [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_operator_(Hilbert_space))

$|(Bx, y) |^2\le (Bx, x)( By, y) $

implies $(Bx, y) =0$ for all $y\in\Bbb{R}^n$

In particular for $y=Bx$ , we have

$(Bx, Bx)=0$ implies $Bx=0$ i.e $x\in\ker(B) $

Hence $\ker(A) \subset \ker(B) $ implies $\dim \ker A\leq \dim \ker B$

Hence the conclusion.